# Virtual Box Symbols MacOS

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I run a bitnami VM on Virtual Box on MacOS Version: **10.15**

I can't write these 4 symbols: `[]{}`

I can't copy and paste into the running VM as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by **reseting** the **keyboard settings**!

Before **german keyboard**.

After **standard english keyboard**.

Conclusion do not ever use **german keyboard**.